# Retrieve a variable after simulating some data

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a simulink model which I am running through a function , all the values to the blocks are assigned from within the function using `assignin()` function , now I want to retrieve the resulting data which is which is automatically saved in the workspace after simulation(I am using 'To workspace' block which stores the simulated result in a vector) , now I want to retrieve this data right after the simulation with the function. I used `evalin()` to retrieve the data from the workspace but it doesn't seem to work as it says the variable is undefined

Comment: There's no need to assign the data (from within your function) to the Base Workspace using `assignin`.  Use the `SrcWorkspace` optional input to the [sim](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/sim.html) function instead.

Comment: The above comment should more explicit and say that you should just define the variables locally within your function, and then using the `SrcWorkspace` option you can specify that your model gets the data it needs from the `caller` workspace, not the (default) `base` workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem , Before I simulate the data I should enable the signal logging for the output first , then assign the simulation output to a variable as an object

```
FO =sim(filename,time);
```

after that I can retrieve the data variable to which the singal was logged from the simulation object

```
FT = FO.get('FT');
```

this works even with in a function unlike the 'To workspace' block

Comment: There's no need to manually change your model to enable signal logging before using `sim`.   Just use the `SignalLogging` optional input to the [sim](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/sim.html) function instead.  The first example in the `sim` doc shows how to do this.